# Java process exitValue bug

Tags: java, multithreading, process, lftp

I am getting "0" value while calling exitValue() for java process object in linux but occasionally child threads (error & output stream readers) are not completed and getting stuck in join. Shouldn't "0" value of exitValue() of process guarantee that all sub processes terminated successfully?

```
private class ReadStdoutThread extends Thread {
        private Process m_prc;
        private StringBuffer m_sb;

        public ReadStdoutThread(Process prc, StringBuffer sb) {
            m_prc = prc;
            m_sb = sb;
        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedReader stdout =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_prc.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
                    m_sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                stdout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ReadStderrThread extends Thread {
        private Process m_prc;
        private StringBuffer m_sb;

        public ReadStderrThread(Process prc, StringBuffer sb) {
            m_prc = prc;
            m_sb = sb;
        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedReader stderr =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_prc.getErrorStream()));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Stderr: " + line);
                    m_sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                stderr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String runCmd(String cmd, long timeoutMS) throws IOException,
                                                                   InterruptedException {
        Process prc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        long startTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isRunning = true;
        System.out.println("Command has started.");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        ReadStdoutThread ot = new HostCommand().new ReadStdoutThread(prc, sb);
        ReadStderrThread et = new HostCommand().new ReadStderrThread(prc, sb);
        ot.start();
        et.start();
        if (timeoutMS == 0) {
            System.out.println("Thread will wait until command is completed.");
            prc.waitFor();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command timeout (ms): " + timeoutMS);
            synchronized (prc) {
                int n = -1;
                while (isRunning) {
                    prc.wait(1000);
                    try {
                        n = prc.exitValue();
                        System.out.println("Command has completed with value: " +
                                           n);
                        m_processExitValue = n;
                        isRunning = false;
                    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
                        // command is still running
                        isRunning = true;
                    }
                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMS >
                         timeoutMS) && isRunning) {
                        System.out.println("Timeout has reached, and command is still running.  Command will be interrupted.");
                        prc.destroy();
                        m_processExitValue = n;
                        isRunning = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            ot.join(timeoutMS);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        try {
            et.join(timeoutMS);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: If process has successfully finished it returns 0, Else throws IllegalThreadStateException, if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated.

Comment: Is sub process means threads in this case? I am getting return value as "0" for exitValue but threads of process are not completed and stuck in join occasionally (0.01%).

Comment: No Its not thread. Its your main Process creating instance of a subclass of Process, that's why sub-process.

Comment: Also, 'm not getting why are you terming threads, "ReadStdoutThread ot , ReadStderrThread et" as child thread of Process prc. Please check your code.

Comment: Two threads (output & error) are required to read from stream.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the ReadStdoutThread  and ReadStderrThread have finished execution. There is no sync between Process's waitFor API and the two seperate thrards that you have spawned to read the standard input and error streams from the Process. You need to use : ot.join();et.join() after invoking ot.start();et.start();

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the method should return a IllegalThreadStateException if any subprocess is not yet terminated, otherwise it will return 0 which indicates normal termination.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Agree but can it be considered as bug in java/linux if process return "0" but still thread has not completed its execution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the ReadStdoutThread  and ReadStderrThread have finished execution. There is no sync between Process's `waitFor` API and the two seperate threads that you have spawned to read the standard input and error streams from the Process. You need to use : `ot.join();et.join();` after invoking `ot.start();et.start();`.Basically, join should be invoked before calling `Process.waitFor()`